# How do I customize the Bot Framework Web Chat title?

Tags: botframework

I embedded the WebChat in a demo page and copied the CSS file, but I don't knwo wehre to change the title of the webchat?

[image]

```
<link href="BotStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="BotChatGoesHere"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>

<!-- If you do not want to use Cognitive Services library, comment out the following line -->
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript or jquery to programmatically change the text. Either

```
document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header")[0].innerHTML = "<span>Chat</span>";
```

or

```
$(".wc-header span").innerText = "Hello";
```