# BotFramework - chatTitle option for V4

Tags: botframework

Migrating from BotFramework V3 to V4, not able to set the chatTitle of chat window. 
This is my old code

```
BotChat.App({
      user: { id: userID, name: 'test' },
      botConnection: botConnection,
      locale: 'fr-fr',
      showUploadButton: false,
      chatTitle: 'Assistant virtuel',
      resize: 'detect'
  })
```

Now with new version, 'chatTitle' is no longer working.

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
     {
        directLine: webChatConnection,
        userID: userID,
        username: 'test',
        locale: 'fr-fr',
        chatTitle: 'Assistant virtuel',
      },
       document.getElementById('botDiv')
     );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this issue [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1551#issuecomment-451236327)

> We omitted the chat title in Web Chat v4 (compare to v3) because:
>
> It is one of the most popular customization
>
> It can be easily done in HTML by appending HTML code just before Web Chat DOM element
>
> It is more intuitive to do it in plain HTML than "customizing" in Web Chat, feel over-engineered if we do it that way
>
> In this way, the user can customize the title as much as they want, for example, adding buttons to the chat title easily.

Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534169/how-do-i-customize-the-bot-framework-web-chat-title) here if it has what you need using Javascript